# invalid iOS deployment version '-miphoneos-version-min=11.0', iOS 10 is the maximum deployment target for 32-bit targets

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

[image]

when I try build or run a Project so that time given error.i remove armv7 and 7s architecture still given error so help me for finding solution

Comment: IOS 11 accept 64 bit. Please read this: [Upgrading to 64 bit iOS Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/iphone-64bit.html)

Comment: iOS 11+ don't support 32bit code. How and where did you disable armv7/7s? On the screenshot I can see that pods (probably for googl ads sdk) are build for arm7

Answer (score 19):

I switched "Architectures" to "Standard Architectures", under the "Build Settings" tab, and the problem has gone. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: For me fix was Architecture to Standard architecture(as shown in the above image) in Build setting and deployment target is 10.0

Comment: This solved my issue after upgrading from iOS ver. 8.0 to 12.3

Answer (score 0):

First locate the target that is giving you the problem, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> worked for me looking for "target = 11". In my case it was a pods, once located I reduced it to 10, I cleaned the build folder, compiled and it worked.

If you need your target to be in a version higher than 10, you can exclude the architecture that is giving you the error.